# Generating an XML file from HTML form input

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to generate an XML document from html form input using PHP all on a LAMP stack. I can generate the XML document, but I seem to be having problems brining in the data from the html field.

I am trying to call `$_POST['itemName']` as a text item in my PHP code, but I am getting an error that says that `itemName` is undefined. Please see the partial `index.html` document and full `generate.php` code below:

```
Here is the full `generate.php` code:

<?php

$dom = new DomDocument('1.0'); 

$orders = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('orders')); 

$order = $orders->appendChild($dom->createElement('order')); 

$item = $order->appendChild($dom->createElement('item'));

$item->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($_POST['itemName']));

$dom->formatOutput = true;
$orders = $dom->saveXML();
$dom->save('orders.xml');

?>
```

Here is the form section from `index.html`:

```
<form name="form1" action="generate.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemName" 
    placeholder="Item Name">

    <button type='submit' action='submit' name='generate'>Generate XML</button>
</form>
```

I expect to get an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <item>text from form field</item>
  </order>
</orders>
```

What I get is the following error displayed in the browser:

```
Notice: Undefined index: itemName in generate.php on line 17
```

I have test the Apache Server and PHP on my local machine, and it works correctly, so the problem definitely lies within my code.

I feel like this is really simple and I am making a pretty obvious mistake, but I don't really know PHP, so this is all kind of new to me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see an input element with name (not id) "itemName" in your form.

Comment: Thanks @miken32! I can't believe I missed that. The duplicate you linked to also answered my question about assigning values to PHP variables. Thanks!

Comment: Common mistake, now you know what to check next time you see it!